# Why does the printf("%c", 0.21) results in 'ß'?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

So, here's my C code. While I was toying with my code in order to learn the format specifiers, especially `%c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    double a = 0.21;
    printf("%c", a);
}
```

I happened to encounter that even if I pass a floating value as an argument in `printf()` function for the format specifier `%c`, the compiler (my compiler is **gcc**) somehow converts the value `0.21` into decimal value `223` which corresponds to ASCII character `ß`.

For `a = 0.22` the output is: `)` whose decimal value in ASCII table is `29`

I ran the code on both **VS code** and **CLion** IDEs, but the results were same. Now it is making me scratch my head for days and I can't figure it out.

I want to know how the values `0.21` and `0.22` are getting converted into the decimal `223` and `29` or how they correspond to the ASCII 223 and 29 i.e. `ß` and `)` respectively.

Since the value 0.21, 0.22 does not corresponds to any of the ASCII, I was expecting the program to print nothing.

But based on the output I thought that this might have something to do with the binaries.
As 0.21 in binary is 0.00110101110000101000111101011100... 
& 223 is 11011111
and 0.22 in binary is 0.00111000010100011110101110000101...
& 29 is 00011101

And I could not find any conversion pattern.

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Is there a way to find out that behavior. Because these are not random running the code again and again results in same output that means it must have some sort of fixed process going on in the compiler.

Comment: As for what really happens is that the `printf` function will read a single byte and display it as a character. Which byte depends on the underlying hardware (byte ordering), and which character depends on the terminal settings.

Comment: And talking about encoding, please note that plain ASCII is a *seven* bit encoding, with values from `0` to `127`.

Comment: Also note that a decent compiler should warn about this. If you don't get a warning, you need to enable more warnings. And treat then as errors that *must* be fixed.

Comment: Now that you mentioned about terminal setting and stuff, I'm getting it a bit.
if I ran printf("%c", 2); the output on my desktop terminal was a white smiley face but on my phone, nothing was printed. Because the hardware and the terminal setting were different and also the compiler used was different.

Comment: `double` argument may be passed via floating point register, so speculation on output prediction for `%c` depending on argument binary representation makes no sence.

Comment: See [C11 Standard - fprintf 7.21.6.1(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) `"If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."`

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads (usually) to *warnings during compilation* (if you set the flags and the compiler checks that).

Comment: Re “ASCII character `ß`”: “ß” is not an ASCII character. ASCII is only a code for 128 values, and they do not include “ß”. The code used for “ß” varies between character encoding systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a `float` (which is automatically converted to a `double` in this case) for a `%c` has undefined behavior.  `printf` looks for the argument where you program would have passed it if its type was `int` or a smaller type that promotes to `int` and uses that value.  In your case the value happens to be 223 or 29 depending on circumstances and it could be something else on a different CPU, or after any unrelated change in the program or even just at a different time or place... The behavior is undefined, you could also get no output or a program crash (unlikely but not impossible).

Use compiler warnings to try and detect such problems (**gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror**) and avoid scratching your head trying to make sense of undefined behavior.

Comment: In ordinary C implementations, changing `a = .21` to `a = .22` does not change the circumstances in any way that would change the output from character 223 to character 29 unless it is using the bytes encoding the `double`. E.g., it does not change the values left in the registers by the startup code or any other data in the program besides the bytes stored in `a`. So it does not seem to be a likely explanation that the program is printing character 223 or 29 just due to “circumstances.”

Comment: Investigation shows 41, the ASCII code for the “)” OP sees, is the low byte of the `double` encoding of `0.22`, and 225, used in some character encodings for the “ß” OP sees, is the low byte of the encoding of `0.21`, so this is most likely `printf` using the low byte of the passed `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: thank you for this insight.  This behavior seems specific to the Microsoft compiler.  both clang nor gcc behave differently as can be seen and investigated using [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/GMxeEMfMz)

Answer (score 2):

> my compiler is gcc

Most probably you are working on X86-64 system. This architecture has separate floating point and normal [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register). When `printf` tries to get the register for `%c` it reads a normal register, but `, a` sets a floating point register.

The value of `%c` is unrelated to `a`. Most probably, it is some leftover register value from `main` initialization, like `_start` or `environ`.

Comment: If the value printed came from some leftover register value, it would not change when `a = .21` is changed to `a = .22`. In ordinary C environments, such a change would only change the bytes used to represent `a`. It would not change how the startup code operates and so would not change what values in leaves in registers.

Comment: Investigation shows 41, the ASCII code for the “)” OP sees, is the low byte of the `double` encoding of `0.22`, and 225, used in some character encodings for the “ß” OP sees, is the low byte of the encoding of `0.21`, so this is most likely `printf` using the low byte of the passed `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a float or double for a %c has undefined behavior. period.

It wouldn't be "undefined behavior" if we could define "why" 0.21 results in 'ß'.

But we can assume that maybe your `printf`'s implementation is binary-casting it to `int`, and that the resulting value did depending on CPU arch, result to 'ß'.

Comment: Re “It wouldn't be "undefined behavior" if we could define "why" 0.21 results in 'ß'.”: No, it would not be “undefined behavior” as the C standard defines it if **the C standard** could define why 0.21 results in “ß”. The C standard does not specify that “undefined behavior” means there is no definition or that **we** cannot define it, it only specifies that it means **it** does not define it. “Undefined behavior” only rescinds any requirements the C standard makes. It does not rescind or alter any requirements from other sources.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "C standard does not specify that ... we cannot define it": Maybe, but “undefined behavior” means there are many varying implementation, like mine for example, hence whatever you/we "define" can't be true for all implementations, and would just be a big lie ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> For `a = 0.22` the output is: `)` whose decimal value in ASCII table is `29`

That is incorrect. The ASCII code for “)” is 41 in decimal. It is 29 in hexadecimal. And 41 (29<sub>16</sub>) is the low byte of the bits used to encode `0.22` in `double`, as shown below. Further, the character you are seeing for `0.21`, “ß”, is encoded as 225 (E1<sub>16</sub>) in some character encoding systems, and 225 is the low byte of the bits used to encode `0.21` in `double`.

As a simple test, you can set `a` to `0x1p52 + x`, where `x` is any integer from 0 to 255, inclusive. Because of `double` numbers are encoded, `0x1p52 + x` will produce an encoding with `x` in the low byte. For example, if this is what is happening on your system, using `a = 0x1p52 + 88` will print “X”, the character with ASCII code 88.

Here is how the `double` resulting from `0.22` in source code is represented in the format most commonly used for `double`, IEEE-754 binary64:

- 0.22 in binary is 0.00111000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111…
- We normalize it by separating an exponent factor, 2<sup>*e*</sup>, and a significand (the fraction portion of a floating-point representation), with the exponent selected so the significand is at least 1 but less than 2 (10 in binary):<sup>1</sup>
  2<sup>−3</sup>•1.11000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111…
- The format uses 53-bit significands, so the significand is rounded to 53 bits. The first 53 bits of the significand are 1.1100001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101000. The next bits begin 111101011… Since these begin with 1 and contain further 1 bits, the trailing portion is more than ½ of the least significant of the 53 bits, so the number is rounded up. The significand that will be encoded is 1.1100001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101001.
- The number is encoded using three fields: A bit to indicate the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 52 bits for the significand.
- The sign bit is 0, to indicate “+”.
- The exponent is encoded by adding 1023 and converting to 11 binary digits. −3 + 1023 = 1020, which is 01111111100 in binary.
- The leading bit of the significand is known to be one from the exponent encoding (the reserved code of zero is used for subnormal significands). The remaining 52 bits of the significand are used for the significand field.
- So the resulting bits are 0 01111111100 1100001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101001.
- Formed into groups of eight bits, this is 00111111 11001100 00101000 11110101 11000010 10001111 01011100 00101001.
- In decimal, that is 63, 204, 40, 245, 194, 143, 92, 41.

Observe the last byte is 41, matching the “)” you saw. One behavior that is seen when `%c` is incorrectly used is that the value from one byte of the passed argument is used. For example, the calling routine may pass the eight bytes used to encode a `double` number, but `printf` is expected just the four bytes of an `int` (`%c` takes an `int` value, of which it effectively prints one byte). So `printf` took four bytes from where it expected to find an `int`, converted those four bytes to `unsigned char`, and printed the resulting character. The C standard does not define this behavior, but it is a potential result.

For `0.21`, the bytes of the encoded `double` are 63, 202, 225, 71, 174, 20, 122, 225. You reported 223, not 225, but I suspect your system is using a character encoding in which “ß” is 225, not 223. For example, [code page 852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852), has “ß” in the E1<sub>16</sub> (225) spot.

It is a little unusual for the bytes for a `double` to be taken for an integer argument these days. It essentially requires passing arguments on the stack instead of in processor registers, as today’s processors commonly use separate registers for floating-point and integer types.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The format has limits on how or low the exponent can go. These are not applicable here and so are not covered in detail. When the exponent is too high, the conversion to `double` results in a representation of infinity. When the exponent is too low, the significand will not be normalized, and a special exponent code is used to represent a subnormal value.

Comment: This seems a plausible explanation for the OP's reported behavior, but it seems specific to the Microsoft compiler and is not guaranteed in any way.  Both clang nor gcc behave differently as can be seen and investigated using [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/GMxeEMfMz)